# mysql query error insert joined select

Tags: java, mysql, sql

hi i have problem on my mysql query
i wanna insert result of joined select query and another data

this is my query
check and advise me please

```
    INSERT INTO TB_AUTO_BAN
    (MEMO,
    REG_DATE,
    USER_ID,
    NAME,
    PHONE_NUM
    )
    VALUES(
    'test',
    NOW(),
    SELECT
    a.USER_ID, a.NAME, a.CONTACT_NUM
    FROM TB_CONTACT AS a INNER JOIN TB_CONTACT_GROUP AS b 
    ON a.GROUP_CONTACT_SEQ = b.GROUP_CONTACT_SEQ 
    WHERE b.USER_ID= 'spark@naver.com' AND b.GROUP_CONTACT_SEQ = 12000)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is as below

```
  INSERT INTO TB_AUTO_BAN
    (MEMO,
    REG_DATE,
    USER_ID,
    NAME,
    PHONE_NUM
    )

    SELECT 
    'test',NOW(),
    a.USER_ID, a.NAME, a.CONTACT_NUM
    FROM TB_CONTACT AS a INNER JOIN TB_CONTACT_GROUP AS b 
    ON a.GROUP_CONTACT_SEQ = b.GROUP_CONTACT_SEQ 
    WHERE b.USER_ID= 'spark@naver.com' AND b.GROUP_CONTACT_SEQ = 12000
```

Comment: forgot to remove the last bracket at end of select query..check edit